# Any product attribute mapping dictonary for retail available?

Tags: java, dictionary, wordnet

I am looking for a product attribute mapping dictionary to use in my project.

Open source will be preferable. I have seen for **WordNet**. But it seems like a general English dictionary.

Hence my question is
- Is there any open source / paid product attribute mapping dictionary available to use?

Can we use WordNet to return me the product attribute related result?

> Example, currently If I am searching for 'memory', wordnet is
>   returning me, S: (n) memory, remembering S: (n) memory, retention,
>   retentiveness, retentivity S: (n) memory, computer memory, storage,
>   computer storage, store, memory board

Instead I only need the results to be product attribute specific.

Comment: Can you give a more accurate example since **memory** doesn't look like a product?What results should you get if you search for **shoe**?

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like [this product](http://www.nopcommerce.com/featurelist.aspx). **Nopcommerce** is listed as open source but in c#. I see a link on their site to download source but that requires an account creation.